# How to capture wifi traffic on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless

I have tried many ways but I can't capture any traffic on wireless interfaces. I can set my wireless interface on "monitor mode", but I can't log any traffic with wireshark, airmon-ng or tcpdump.

```
iw list
Wiphy phy0
[...]
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

I have tried stop networking, NetworkManager and `/etc/init.d/networking`.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
Linux V3580 5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 13:34:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Capturing wifi traffic seems to be easy:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Thank you for your replies.

`sudo tcpdump wlan0` (`wlp3s0`) - doesn't work. I can't capture any packets.

I understand that `ifconfig` is deprecated but it still works. I means I can shut down wireless interfaces, etc.

Comment: Doesn't `sudo tcpdump wlan0`  (or similar in wireshark) produce tcp/ip traffic output ?